# Reaching a docker container through a dockerized openvpn from a client

Tags: docker, networking, openvpn

I'm trying to reach a docker container through a vpn tunnel. The target docker container and the openvpn docker container are both on the same remote machine.

#### So far I have,

- created a docker network with a bridge driver on subnet `172.18.0.0/16` with gateway `172.18.0.1`
- attached a nginx container to this network : [nginxdemos/hello](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello/)
- created a pki
- deployed an openvpn server in a container with the subnet `10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0`
- attached the openvpn server container to the docker network 172.18.0.0/16
- started an openvpn client

#### What is working :

- I can ping my openvpn server from my openvpn client
- I can ping nginxdemos/hello from the openvpn server container

#### What I can't do :

- reach nginxdemos/hello from my openvpn client. On a browser from the openvpn client, I expect to type the ip `10.8.0.1` and be forwarded to the nginx container.
  I suppose I missed some routing properties in openvpn.

If anyone can help me on this I would be really grateful

I tried to add this line to the server conf :
`push "route 172.18.0.0 255.255.0.0"`
but no success.

I looked into my openvpn container but there seems to be not iptables in it.

#### The docker image for openvpn :

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add openvpn bash openrc
RUN rc-update add openvpn default

EXPOSE 1194/udp

CMD openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

#### I run this image with

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/server-private-pki:/etc/openvpn --device=/dev/net/tun --privileged docker-openvpn /bin/sh
```

#### The openvpn server conf file :

```
port 1194
;proto tcp
proto udp
dev tun

# private
ca    /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert  /etc/openvpn/{{openvpn_server_name}}.crt
dh    /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
key   /etc/openvpn/{{openvpn_server_name}}.key

# server config
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

push "route 172.18.0.0 255.255.0.0"

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
cipher AES-256-CBC
keepalive 10 60

# downgrade privileges
user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

# log
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

#### The iptables on the machine hosting the vpn and the nginx demo

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  110 15960 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  110 15960 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   51  8583 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    6   252 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   53  7125 ACCEPT     all  --  br-8e169a773f9d !br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-8e169a773f9d br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   252 ACCEPT     udp  --  !br-8e169a773f9d br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           udp dpt:1194

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   53  7125 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-8e169a773f9d !br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  110 15960 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-8e169a773f9d  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   53  7125 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  110 15960 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I also tried to active ipv4 forwarding on the client, the vps hosting the docker network and on the openvpn containerwith no success.
I alson added on these 3 OS the following iptables rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But still nothing.

Last thing, I had already several docker networks on the client, I changed the subnet of the docker network on the server to a free subnet to avoid collisions and I updated the server config file (push directive) accordingly.

I can see this new route (127.100.0.0) on my client and I can ping 127.100.0.3 (openvpn server container ip) from the client.

Still working on this, `127.100.0.2` still unreachable.

Comment: Could you please post the iptables rules on the docker host?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, I have posted the iptables. I'm thinkin that my understanding might be incomplete. Maybe I should try to connect directly to the IP of the dockerized nginx so ` 172.18.0.2 ` from my client. I should maybe try to understand which configuration is missing to achieve this ?